# Using the stats package in R for kmeans clustering

Tags: r, clustering

I'm having difficulty understanding one or two aspects of the cluster package. I'm following the example from [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html) closely, but don't understand one or two aspects of the analysis. I've included the code that I am using for this particular example.

```
## Libraries
library(stats)
library(fpc) 

## Data
mydata = structure(list(a = c(461.4210925, 1549.524107, 936.42856, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 131.4349206, 0, 762.6110846, 
3837.850406), b = c(19578.64174, 2233.308842, 4714.514274, 0, 
2760.510002, 1225.392118, 3706.428246, 2693.353714, 2674.126613, 
592.7384164, 1820.976961, 1318.654162, 1075.854792, 1211.248996, 
1851.363623, 3245.540062, 1711.817955, 2127.285272, 2186.671242
), c = c(1101.899095, 3.166506463, 0, 0, 0, 1130.890295, 0, 654.5054857, 
100.9491289, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 789.091922, 0, 0, 0, 0), d = c(33184.53871, 
11777.47447, 15961.71874, 10951.32402, 12840.14983, 13305.26424, 
12193.16597, 14873.26461, 11129.10269, 11642.93146, 9684.238583, 
15946.48195, 11025.08607, 11686.32213, 10608.82649, 8635.844964, 
10837.96219, 10772.53223, 14844.76478), e = c(13252.50358, 2509.5037, 
1418.364947, 2217.952853, 166.92007, 3585.488983, 1776.410835, 
3445.14319, 1675.722506, 1902.396338, 945.5376228, 1205.456943, 
2048.880329, 2883.497101, 1253.020175, 1507.442736, 0, 1686.548559, 
5662.704559), f = c(44.24828759, 0, 485.9617601, 372.108855, 
0, 509.4916263, 0, 0, 0, 212.9541122, 80.62920455, 0, 0, 30.16525587, 
135.0501384, 68.38023073, 0, 21.9317122, 65.09052886), g = c(415.8909649, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 637.2629479, 0, 0, 
0), h = c(583.2213618, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), i = c(68206.47387, 18072.97762, 23516.98828, 
13541.38572, 15767.5799, 19756.52726, 17676.00505, 21666.267, 
15579.90094, 14351.02033, 12531.38237, 18470.59306, 14149.82119, 
15811.23348, 14637.35235, 13588.64291, 12549.78014, 15370.90886, 
26597.08152)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I standardize the variables:

```
# standardize variables
mydata <- scale(mydata) 

## K-means Clustering 

# Determine number of clusters
wss <- (nrow(mydata)-1)*sum(apply(mydata,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata, centers=i)$withinss)
# Q1
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",  ylab="Within groups sum of squares") 

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 3) # number of values in cluster solution

# get cluster means 
aggregate(mydata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)

# append cluster assignment
mydata <- data.frame(mydata, cluster = fit$cluster)

# Cluster Plot against 1st 2 principal components - vary parameters for most readable graph
clusplot(mydata, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=0, lines=0) # Q2

# Centroid Plot against 1st 2 discriminant functions
plotcluster(mydata, fit$cluster)
```

My question is, how can the plot which shows the number of clusters (marked `Q1` in my code) be related to the actual values (cluster number and variable name) ?

Update: I now understand that the `clusplot()` function is a bivariate plot, with PCA1 and PCA2. However, I don't understand the link between the PCA components and the cluster groups. What is the relationship between the PCA values and the clustering groups? I've read elsewhere about the link between kmeans and PCA, but I still don't understand how they can be displayed on the same bivariate graph.

Comment: apologies if I've asked too many questions about clustering over the last few days. I'm trying to become more familiar with this field quickly (also I did post this question on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997870/using-the-cluster-package-in-r-for-kmeans-clustering but it was suggested to move it here)

Comment: That's ok, this is not TCS.SE (-;

Comment: # Determine number of clusters
Could you explain why we are using this formula (mydata,2,var)
and why 2:15?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not grasp question 1 completely, but I'll attempt an answer. The plot of Q1 shows how the within sum of squares (wss) changes as cluster number changes. In this kind of plots you must look for the kinks in the graph, a kink at 5 indicates that it is a good idea to use 5 clusters.

WSS has a relationship with your variables in the following sense, the formula for WSS is

$\sum_{j} \sum_{x_i \in C_j} ||x_i - \mu_j||^2$

where $\mu_j$ is the mean point for cluster $j$ and $x_i$ is the $i$-th observation. We denote cluster j as $C_j$. WSS is sometimes interpreted as "how similar are the points inside of each cluster". This similarity refers to the variables.

The answer to question 2 is this. What you are actually watching in the  `clusplot()` is the plot of your observations in the principal plane. What this function is doing is calculating the principal component score for each of your observations, plotting those scores and coloring by cluster.

Principal component analysis (PCA) is a dimension reduction technique; it "summarizes" the information of all variables into a couple of "new" variables called components. Each component is responsible of explaining certain percentage of the total variability. In the example you read "This two components explain 73.95% of the total variability".

The function `clusplot()` is used to identify the effectiveness of clustering. In case you have a successful clustering you will see that clusters are clearly separated in the principal plane. On the other hand, you will see the clusters merged in the principal plane when clustering is unsuccessful.

For further reference on principal component analysis you may read wiki. if you want a book I suggest Modern Multivariate Techniques by Izenmann, there you will find PCA and k-means.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had one further question about the `clusplot()` function. What is the relationship between the PCA values, and the clustering groups? I've read elsewhere about the link between kmeans and PCA, but I still don't understand how they can be displayed on the same bivariate graph. (Perhaps this should be a new question in itself).

Comment: That new question wouldn't be clear without its context :)

Comment: Actually, the PCA values and the clustering groups are independent. PCA creates "new" coordinates for each observation in `mydata`, that is what you actually see on the plot. The shape of the points is plotted using `fit$cluster`, the second parameter of `clusplot()`. Maybe you should take a deeper look into PCA. Let me know if this helped you, or if you further references.

Comment: It helps (in the sense that I am honing in on my problem!). How is `fit$cluster` related to the PCA "coordinates"? I think I understand how PCA works, but as I understand it, each Component cannot be explained using variables from the original data (rather it is a linear combination of the raw data), which is why I don't understand how it can be related to the clusters.

Comment: You almost got it :) `fit$cluster` is unrelated to PCA. What `clusplot()` does is to plot the points using the "new" coordinates and label them using `fit$cluster`. I got '+' for cluster 3, 'o' for cluster 1 and a triangle for cluster 2. The function `clusplot()` is useful to visualize the clustering.

Comment: What do you mean by the "new" coordinates and how can they be related to `fit$cluster`? I had thought that the coordinates of PCA1 and PCA2 are completely unrelated to `fit$cluster` This is the part that confuses me, I think. Thank you for your patience in explaining this!

Comment: By the "new" coordinates I mean PCA1 and PCA2. You're right, they are completely unrelated to `fit$cluster` :)

Comment: But if they are unrelated, how can they be plotted on the same axes?

Comment: Remember that `fit$cluster` is a categorical variable indicating the cluster assigned to each observation. It is used to define the labels of the points, that's how they are plotted.

Comment: So, am I correct in thinking that a point, with a cluster category is essential a linear combination, or vector, of the variables? Is the PCA just a rescaling of this vector? (Apologies if my terminology is incorrect). I have read a few papers which talk about the link between kmeans and PCA, which is perhaps why I'm wondering about this. (If I could vote your answer, up more than once I would!).

Comment: :D Indeed, a point in the `clusplot()` is a linear combination of the original variables. Maybe the papers that you mention are about clustering after PCA, but that's definitely another topic.